# How we joined two database tables each other. In PHP simple way

Tags: mysql, join, datatable, inner-join

How I join two table? Yes I reads all various posts on stackoverflow but it is not matching that. Even when I try to create it doesn't happened.

**WHAT IS MY PROBLEM**

I want insert data in `table 2` from `table 1`

**WHAT IS MY PROJECT**

**TABLE 1**

```
customerID   Name       Password      Address
 1001           jinesh     secret        INDIA
 2003           mahesh     secret        USA
```

**INSERT INTO TABLE 2**

```
  ID        UserName  UseePass
   1        jinesh    secret  
   2        mahesh    secrey
```

How I make like this.

**I AM CODING**

```
 // start
 $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO table2 (UserName,UserPass) VALUE($name,$pass) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1 password = $pass");
 // End
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Those comments are full of links with many examples.

Comment: That's on the right track, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (UserName, UseePass) 
SELECT Name, Password FROM table1
```

I'm assuming the ID column in table2 is and auto_increment so I'm skipping it in the insert statement

Comment: Yes, it will take all the rows from the table1 and insert it to the table2.

You can add a where condition to limit/filter  the number of rows added